# Get NSIndexPath of "next" index?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How can I get the index path for an object that does not exist yet, but it will be the next object at the index if it existed? For example, let's say I have a `UICollectionView` like this:

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
- item x

How can I get the path for item x even if it doesn't exist yet? For example, the `indexpath.row` would be 3 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(oldIndexPath.row + 1) inSection:0];
```

Comment: Just remember about limiting it to count of objects you have. use MIN(count, oldIndexPath.row+1).

Comment: Thank you, but how do I get the old index path if I am unable to save the index path when the last object was added? Do I have to do [dataSource count]-1 ?

Comment: Yes: you are responsible for knowing how much data you have and where it is.  You should typically generate your index path based on your data model.  This could be an array, an ordered set, or a different, less common collection type.  It may even be nested arrays, or 2+ different arrays, each as a property on an object.  (Each separate array would typically represent a different section.)

Answer (score 0):

```
int itemIndex = dataSourceCount <= oldIndexPath.row + 1 ? oldIndexPath.row : oldIndexPath.row+1;
IndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:itemIndex inSection:0];
```